# How to attach Visual Studio 2015 debugger to an android app

Tags: android, debugging, toolchain, visual-studio-2015

I have already a tool-chain to build my c++ apps cross platform but it is a mess to debug. It would be nice to attach visual studio to a running app on the device.
Is there anyway to attach the debugger of visual studio 2015 to a running app like to a windows process?

Kindly,
Martin

Comment: I managed to find a workaround. 1) Create a new android native activity project. 2) Remove all the code 3) setup the "Debugging" properties of the packaging project to your apk and your application name. 4) Add your projects to visual studio. 5) compile your code with -g2 -gdwarf-2 for compatible debug information format. 6) Launch project with debugger (F5).

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me. You don't really say where your app comes from, but I'm using the Native-Activity Application (Android) from the New Project dialog. Run in debug mode and use the normal debugging tools.

Comment: Is there a way to debug an app without building? I have the source code and a debug builded package. How do I attach the debugger to the app on the device?
In windows it is no problem to debug a running process as long as I have the .pdb and the binary for the process. I'm looking for a way to do the same with an app.
How do I select my android device in Visual Studio 2015 in "Attach to Process"?

Comment: It seems like it should be possible, but I don't know how, sorry.